# Accept anonymous comparator in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

How can I accept a function to pass to Vector.sortBy() in scala as an argument?

Currently I have a function like this:

```
private def buildTree(data: Vector[Data2D]): Node = {
   var sorted: Vector[Data2D] = data.sortBy(_.x)
   // etc...
 }
```

However, I would like to pass either "_.x" (sort on x) or "_.y" as an argument to the function, so I can do something like this:

```
private def buildTree(data: Vector[Data2D], comparator): Node = {
   var sorted: Vector[Data2D] = data.sortBy(comparator)
   // etc...

   if(comparator == _.x){
       buildTree(data, _.y)
   }

 }
```

So I would like to check what the current "comparator" is, and then recurse passing it the comparator for the y coordinate.

I hope this is clear. In Java I would write it as:

```
private Node buildTree(List<Data2D> data, Comparator<Data2D> comparator) {
 // Sorted on x or y
 Collections.sort(data, comparator);

 // ... snip ...

 if (comparator instanceof XComparator) {
    // Recurse
    Node subtree = buildTree(data, YComparator.INSTANCE);
    ret.setSubtree(subtree);
 }
 return ret;
}

// Then build tree is called like:
Node root = tree.buildTree(data, XComparator.INSTANCE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you want an `Ordering`. Like this:

```
class XOrdering extends Ordering[Data2D] {
    override def compare(x: Data2D, y: Data2D): Int = Ordering.Int(x.x, y.x)
}

class YOrdering extends Ordering[Data2D] {
    override def comapre(x: Data2D, y: Data2D): Int = Ordering.Int(x.y, y.y)
}

private def buildTree(data: Vector[Data2D], ordering: Ordering[Data2D]): Node = {
   var sorted: Vector[Data2D] = data.sorted(ordering)
   // etc...

   ordering match {
     case _: XOrdering => buildTree(data, YOrdering)
     case _: YOrdering => buildTree(data, XOrdering)
     case _ => error("I don't know what that ordering is!")
   }
 }
```

The `sortBy` method just creates an `Ordering` for you. `sortBy(_.x)` is equivalent to `sorted(Ordering.by(_.x))`.

Comment: Sorry but where did "comparator" come from?

Comment: @drozzy Sorry, I didn't understand your question well. I'll try to modify this.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clear. It's just before you had a "comparator" variable that was not defined anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

If you check the docs, you see that `sortBy` takes one argument: `f: A => B`.  Looks like a generic function that takes `A` as an argument and produces a `B`.  So, let's give that a try:

```
val orderX = (d: Data2D) => d.x
val orderY = (d: Data2D) => d.y
```

which defines the two functions that we want.  Now we can call

```
data.sortBy(orderer)
```

and test

```
if (orderer==orderX) buildTree(data, orderY)
```

(though I would recommend passing in both comparators as arguments rather than searching for specific constants).

Comment: What do you mean passing both comparators instead of searching for specific constants? Also - can you show me how the buildTree method signature will look? Thanks!

Comment: `def buildTree(data: Vector[Data2D], orderers: (Data2D => Int, Data2D => Int)`, assuming that `Data2D` has `Int`s.  You sort with `orderers._1`, recurse with `orderers.swap`, and pass in on the external call `(_.x, _.y)`.